# Vaadin 23, component sizing optimization problem (Textfield, Select, etc.)

Tags: java, vaadin

I am trying to make my web app look identical on all screens. Essentially, I want my website to have the same appearance regardless of the resolution on user side.

I am already using vw and vh to set size, but some components (at least TextField, Select) have inner html code that seems to be completely unaffected by what I can do in Java, as well as parent css properties. For example:

[image: ""]

Buttons looking not too bad, but TextField... I did set font size to be 1vw through css properties, but that only effects placeholder. I don't know, is there a way to bind all inner components of, for example TextField, to vw, vh of my choosing?

Comment: Not sure how you are trying to apply your styles, but I think the following documentation can help with what you want: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/styling/custom-theme/creating-custom-theme/#vaadin-component-styles

Comment: "I did set font size to be 1vw through css properties": what properties did you set and on what selectors?

Comment: @Jouni I set "font-size" property through `getStyle().set("font-size", "1vw")`. This should set css property in general. However some Vaadin components consists of many HTML parts, and so this works perfectly for some like Button, but not for others like TextField, where this sets only font size for placeholder, or Select<> where this does essantially nothing.

Comment: This [issue](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/18171457/how-to-change-drawer-size) has helped me a bit. But then I don't really now part names for components. For example, vaadin-text-field has input part, label part, error message part, but I still have no clue how to address them in css to set properties.

Comment: @STaefi Yeah, but the problem is that when I use certain parameters for my componet in general, for example, setting width and height with java code, or setting font-size with separate css file that I import, or also just directly setting css property with `getStyle().set("property", "value")` - it get applied only for component  itself, but not for it's parts. And so I get that TextField FlexBox is with correct width and height, but not the html input, and when I change screen size then FlexBox remains the same, but input always varies.

Comment: “how to address them [styleable parts] in css to set properties“: use the `::part()` pseudo-element selector, for example, `::part(label)` in your global style sheet (styles.css).

Comment: As the font-size of text field labels is explicitly set to var(--lumo-font-size-s), the font size on the host, which you set with `getStyle().set("font-size", 1vw")`, will not affect it, and you need to set the font size of the label explicitly as well. The easiest way is to override the Lumo tokens/custom properties. I wrote an answer for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all font sizes to adapt to the viewport width, you should override all Lumo font-size tokens/properties: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/styling/lumo/design-tokens/typography/#lumo-font-size

For example:

frontend/themes/mytheme/styles.css:

```css
html {
  --lumo-font-size-xxxl: 2.5vw;
  --lumo-font-size-xxl: 1.75vw;
  --lumo-font-size-xl: 1.375vw;
  --lumo-font-size-l: 1.125vw;
  --lumo-font-size-m: 1vw;
  --lumo-font-size-s: 0.875vw;
  --lumo-font-size-xs: 0.8125vw;
  --lumo-font-size-xxs: 0.75vw;
}
```